# How to add condition that only allows to select 2 options from dropdown list in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to add a condition in Functional area in SharePoint which would only allow to select 2 options from dropdown list. How can I do that?

---

Can we edit, add column in existing one in SharePoint? If yes can anyone please tell me?

Comment: just create a choice column and create 2 options.  Don't allow people to type in their own -> set "Allow 'Fill-in' choices" to No.

Comment: HI Tally, Thanks

Comment: I have one another question that can I edit , add column in share point? if yes can you please tell me.

Comment: Hi tally, i want to set that only can choose 2 option from many(100) .

Comment: You would probably need to use custom coding, perhaps javascript to restrict the number of options chosen to two.  Typically users can select either 1 option or multiple (as many as they like).  If you want a no-code option, why not create two columns and restrict users to selecting one option from each column?